# How to make Unity animator not a headache?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have recently followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkiSJ5z-hE&t=978s and, after replacing my animator transitions and parameters with `animator.Play()`, all my animations are a bit glitchy (all I have is a playerMovement script). For example, after jumping, the player is still in the "run" animation. This is just one of many.
The question is: What is the industry-standard way of handling multiple animations without creating a spiderweb in the animator?

Thank you for taking time to answer!

Comment: well yes they will be glitchy because there are no transitions.. why do you ahte the animator so much?

Comment: In my opinion, the video linked gives some pretty awful advice. The "spiderweb" *is* the logic of your animation system - you *could* express that in some code like your source does, but the complexity is only moved, not removed. The "web" also has some huge benefits like making visually clear which transitions are legal and allowing a designer to easily modify the animation transitions. This is all possible in code but I promise it will be way more of a mess than any web would be to achieve the same effect for anything non-trivial...